# Selective reduction of nitro group to amine, in benzene ring containing nitrile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, organic-reduction, nitro-compounds, nitriles

I would like to know if there is a possible route of synthesis that may reduce 3-nitrobenzonitrile **A** to 3-aminobenzonitrile **B**.

[image]

I would normally reduce a nitro to an amine using $\ce{Pd/C}$ and $\ce{H2}$, but since the nitrile is sensitive to this method, I need an alternative.

Comment: Clarification: If there are easier methods to arrive at product "B" through alternative reactions, besides reduction from "A", then I would gladly hear them.

Comment: I think it would also works using Fe/HCl

Comment: So would Sn/HCl or Zn/HCl

Comment: Sure! There are some "active metals" that would work

Comment: I just did a Chem Abstracts search of this reaction with 3031 hits! Many of them involve hydrogenations. Hope you have access.

Comment: I was always a fan of Zn dust/NH4Cl (see e.g. Chem. Sci., 2012,3, 537)

Answer (score 8):

My answer is intended to support Waylander's suggestion elsewhere. I thought it'd be better to give OP some insight of this reduction mentioned (Ref.1). To my knowledge, after doing thorough literature search, the aromatic nitro group reduction by $\ce{SnCl2.2H2O}$ is the best method so far in the presence of other sensitive  groups such as nitrile group on the aromatic nucleus. The abstract of the reference 1 stated that:

> Aromatic nitro compounds are readily reduced by $\ce{SnCl2.2H2O}$ in alcohol or ethyl acetate or by anhydrous $\ce{SnCl2}$ in alcohol where other reducible or acid sensitive groups such as aldehyde, ketone, ester, cyano, halogen, and *O*-benzyl remain unaffected.

This point is depicted in following diagram as two examples given in Ref.1:

[image: Nitro Reduction]

However, as shown in the separate box in the diagram (under the title, *Stephen reduction of nitriles*), if you use $\ce{HCl}$ (hydrogen chloride gas) with $\ce{SnCl2}$ as other suggestions, the result would be different (Ref.2). $\ce{HCl}$ is added to the nitrile group to give the imidoyl chloride salt first, which is then reduced by the tin(II) chloride. The initial product is the complex with $\ce{SnCl4}$ (which is often crystalline) that is then hydrolyzed to the corresponding aldehyde (see the insert in the diagram).

For the convenience of OP and other readers, I'd include a typical reduction procedure in Ref.1:

> **The reduction of *p*-nitrobenzoic acid:** A mixture of $\pu{1.67 g}$ ($\pu{0.01 mol}$) of *p*-nitrobenzoic acid and $\pu{11.275 g}$ ($\pu{0.05 mol}$) of $\ce{SnCl2.2H2O}$ in $\pu{20 mL}$ of absolute ethanol is heated at $\pu{70 ^\circ C}$ under nitrogen. After $\pu{30 min}$ the starting material has disappeared and the solution is allowed to cool down and then poured into ice. The $\mathrm{pH}$ is made slightly basic ($\mathrm{pH}\ 7-8$) by addition of 5% aqueous sodium bicarbonate before being extracted with ethyl acetate. The organic phase is thoroughly washed with brine, treated with charcoal and dried over sodium sulfate. Evaporation of the solvent leaves $\pu{1.5 g}$ ($94.5\%$) of *p*-aminobenzoic acid, which gives one spot on TLC and melts over $\pu{300 ^\circ C}$.

**References:**

1. F. D. Bellamy, K. Ou, “Selective reduction of aromatic nitro compounds with stannous chloride in non acidic and non aqueous medium,” *Tetrahedron Letters* **1984**, *25(8)*, 839-842 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(01)80041-1).
2. James A. Knight, Harry D. Zook, “Reduction of Aliphatic Nitriles by the Stephen Reaction,” *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1952**, *74(18)*, 4560-4562 (https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01138a031).

Comment: I prefer basifying with 50% NaOH. The initial  basification produces a persistent emulsion of Sn(IV) salts. If you add enough NaOH, Sn(OH)4  forms which goes back into solution and the extraction becomes straightforward.

Comment: @Philip: You should accept Waylander's answer since it is the one prompt me to do some research. And also, it is the best method so far.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne: Thank you for your very expounding answer <3

Comment: @Philip: I'd appreciate if you accept Waylander's answer, because my answer initiated by his reference. :-)

Answer (score 6):

$\ce{SnCl2.2H2O}$ in refluxing $\ce{EtOAc}$ as reported by Bellamy & Ou [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403901800411) will do this very cleanly. Work up into ice then add concentrated $\ce{NaOH}$ until you get phase separation. I have done this transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce a nitro to an amine using 1% Pt on carbon  and $\ce{H2}$, since the nitrile is sensitive to Pd/C catalyst. I have done reduction of this type material using Selective 1% Pt on carbon  grade and low hydrogen pressure, at ton level.

Comment: Please don't use a signature when posting here; your avatar already displays your identity. You are welcome to put contact details on your profile page.